# Powershell trying to set-content of folders instead of files

Tags: powershell

I've got this powershell script that looks for all files in a folder and replaces a string with another string.

```
foreach ($file in (Get-ChildItem "Y:\files\*.config"  -Recurse | select -expand fullname)) 
{
  (  Get-Content $file) -replace 's1', 's2' | Set-Content $file
  write-host ("found s1 at {0}" -f $file)
}
```

But the error I get is:

```
Set-Content : Access to the path 'Y:\files\path\to\file\' is denied.
```

I notice that it seems to be trying to do the Set-Content on the folder the file is in instead of the file, but I have no clue why. The Get-ChildItem in the foreach loop is correctly returning files, not folders. So why is it trying to set the content of the folder the file is in?

edit: I have permission to all files/folders. 
I have tried running powershell as admin

Comment: try to append -raw to the `Get-Content` cmdlet: `(Get-Content $file -raw)`

Comment: What do you get if you run Get-ChildItem "Y:\files\*.config"  -Recurse | ? { $_.PSIsContainer } | Select Fullname

Comment: This code should work. `-raw`  is not required for this code as -replace will work as shown. Should not have to filter folders unless you have folders called folder.config. Is .config in the folder names?

Comment: Maybe the user can read the files but not write to them? So it can be a permission issue like the error says.

Comment: What DarkLite1 said. This code looks fine.

Comment: David I copied and pasted your code into my ISE and created a little test folder, I do see what you are saying is the issue but what are you trying to accomplish in the end? renaming folders?

Comment: Script works as expected on a local drive and a mapped network drive to one of my NAS boxes. Is the `Y:` drive a mapped network drive maybe? Could the permissions be to restrictive for the account running the script?

Comment: I misread your original issue, I confirmed that the code works perfectly fine unless there is nothing in the folder. but your script as is only checks for .config files.

Comment: DarkLite1: I have tried running ISE as admin, and I have RW permissions on everything in the directory.
Matt: No .config folders
Luke: I am just trying to do a basic find-and-replace in the files.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. So many glaze over the little things. If you create a test environment separate from what you are testing now does it work? I bet it does. Permissions is my only thought at this point. Are there any deny rights that might be superseding your RW rights? To clarify when you run as admin you mean that it is running as you with elevated rights?

Comment: Are the files set to read-only?

Comment: Kev: Weird. I had all the permissions I needed on the directory on the network drive, but the script worked as soon as I copied to my machine. If you answer the post I can mark it as the correct answer. Thanks!